# How to sort a list according to a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list:

```
a = ["x", "y", "z"]
```

I have another list of lists:

```
b = [["y", 99], ["w", 65], ["z", 150]]
```

So, I would like to sort items in `a`, according to the values in `b` in descending order, thus the sorted `a` should look like:

```
sorted_a = ["z", "y", "x"]
```

here `"x"` is on the last, because it doesn't have a value in `b`.

I would like to know the fastest way of achieving this, because my real lists are large.

Comment: You don't have a value associated to `x` in `b`. Anyways you could sort the array with a closure that scans `b` to get values for  `x` etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert `b` to a dictionary and sort using `dict.get()` as the key with a default value of 0, for example:

```
a = ["x", "y", "z"]
b = [["y", 99], ["w", 65], ["z", 150]]

lowest = float('-inf')
tmp = dict(b)
sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: tmp.get(x, lowest), reverse=True)
# sorted_a = ["z", "y", "x"]
```

**Edit:**

To avoid wrong results when having negative numbers, I changed the default value for `.get()` to `-inf` so the elements that don't exist in `b` come last in the sorted list. Keep it as `tmp.get(x, 0)` if you don't have negative values in `b`.

Comment: `a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: tmp[x], reverse=True)`

Comment: ah, for default value!

Comment: @bulbus Yeah to avoid raising an exception

Comment: It may fail if any of values are `-neg`

Comment: Why? Negatives should be sorted accordingly by `sorted()`

Comment: The req. is that keys with no vals be at the end, so keys with no vals get sorted ahead of the ones with -ve vals.

Comment: I would suggest saving `float('-inf')` to a constant since it takes some extra time to calculate -inf each time, (this can reduce 0.5 sec of your runtime), btw, nice solution, upvoted

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `defaultdict` and add the values from `b` to the `defaultdict`, then change the `key` of `sorted` to `b_dict[x]`, which will sort according to the value associated with `x` in `b`, if the value doesn’t exist in `b`, the default value was `0`, so it will be sorted to last.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = ["x", "y", "z"]
b = [["y", 99], ["w", 65], ["z", 150]]

b_dict = defaultdict(int, b)

sorted_a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: b_dict[x], reverse=True)
print(sorted_a)
#  ["z", "y", "x"]
```

---

## Speed wise:

1. @Moe A’s answer using `dict.get(x, 0)`, with a timeit value of 2.42482
2. @abccd’s answer (mine) using `defaultdict`, with a timeit value of  2.88044
3. @RomanPerekhrest’s answer using two `sorted` function, with a timeit value of 2.97899

## Result:

> I would like to know the fastest way of achieving this

Then I would suggest using @Moe A’s answer because it is by far the fastest and most simplest out of the three.

Comment: You can initialize the default dictionary directly from the list b: `b_dict = default(int, b)` and skip the for loop

Comment: @Robb thank you! I forgot you can do that :p and went with the long way..

Answer (score 1):

With `sorted` function:

```
a = ["x", "y", "z"]
b = [["y", 99], ["w", 65], ["z", 150]]
b_sorted = [i[0] for i in sorted(b, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]
a_sorted = sorted(a, key=lambda x: b_sorted.index(x) if x in b_sorted else len(a))

print(a_sorted)
```

The output:

```
['z', 'y', 'x']
```